# MySQL + PHP - Best way to store timestamp every time user logs in

Tags: php, mysql

I need to track all of a user's logins, so that every time they log in I have the timestamp of when they did so.  What is the most efficient and best way of doing this?

I have always done it by simply having a text field in the users table that stores unix timestamps separated by a character.  Each time they log in, another timestamp gets added to the end.

```
1243453458|1255476933|1263453743|1318495068|
```

Is this a bad way of doing it? I figured a separate logins table with a row for every time any user logs in is total overkill and will result in far more strain on the DB when retrieving this information.

Bear in mind I process these timestamps in PHP and also create graphs using jQuery from the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that *is* a horrible way of storing anything, including timestamps, and there are much better ways of doing this. Even the simplest table would give you much better performance:

```
user_id (int) | last_login (timestamp)
```

- you're storing the timestamps as string. That's completely inefficient for storage, retrieval, and update; plus you'll run into a column limit eventually.
- there are *heavily optimized* datatypes for this kind of purpose - the MySQL server developers tend to know a thing or two about storing data efficiently.
- the database hit for such a tiny table, with fixed-size rows, will be negligible - as opposed to a table with variable-size strings which requires further processing in the application.

In other words, by trying to optimize the app (based on incorrect assumptions - "another table is too much strain"), you've pessimized it, coming up with an all-around inefficient solution. Don't overcomplicate things; and when in doubt, profile both options and see for yourself.

Comment: Great answer, thanks.  I guess I had this misconception about storage efficiency.

Answer (score 4):

You'd probably be better to put it into a separate table in your database, something like:

```
members_logins
member_id (int) | timestamp (timestamp)
```

It'd mean it would be easier to do operations on.

Comment: this is definitely the best way to do it

Comment: I know this is the best way to do it, I'm just not sure it's worth it to store potentially millions of rows.  Okay, if I wanted to limit the table to storing only the last 50 logins for a user, what is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: `DELETE FROM members_login WHERE timestamp < (SELECT timestamp FROM members_logins ORDER BY timestamp LIMIT 50,1)`

Comment: @BadHorsie: This is performant enough even for *trillions* of such rows, both on read and write. Limiting the table for the last n logins is pointless - just `limit` the read query to `50`.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql you can use a TIMESTAMP

Have a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html) on how to configure it

EDIT: Your pipe delimited approach is no good. You could have a transactions table storing all sorts of user events.